# ECSS Simulation Modelling Portability

Tags: simulation

Is there anyone who applied "ECSS-E-ST-40-07C Space engineering – Simulation modelling platform standard" to their simulation?

I wonder is the standard really applicable or applied by someone. Some of specification explained by referencing to a file which name is ZIPFILE (Ex; ECSS-E-ST-40-07C-DIR1->Page 33 ->5.1.1 Title) but I couldn't find the file and anyone knows where the file. Eventually, My real question is how can I apply the standard and verify that?

The standard pdf's link;
http://ecss.nl/get_attachment.php?file=2018/10/ECSS-E-ST-40-07C-DIR1(23October2018).pdf

Free access (no registration required) link: https://archive.org/download/ecssest4007cdir123october2018/ECSS-E-ST-40-07C-DIR1%2823October2018%29.pdf

Comment: This document is a draft. Hopefully someone submitted a comment about the ZIPFILE.

Comment: Oh. My. And I thought US standards (particularly DoD and NASA standards) were the ultimate in mandating "This is how you shall do it (so as to ensure it is done badly)". I'm thinking of the Simulation Interoperability Standards Organization family of standards. It looks like Europe has one-upped the United States.

Comment: US government uses HLA for sim interoperability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulation modelling platform (ECSS-E-ST-40-07) has published with all contents, which is a standard based on ECSS-E-ST-40 for the engineering of simulation software.

The Standard PDF's and ZIPFILE's Links;

https://ecss.nl/standard/ecss-e-st-40-07c-simulation-modelling-platform-2-march-2020/